# Mysql NEW table does not exist

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a simple trigger for testing purpose but I get an error telling me:

```
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'NEW' in field list
```

This is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER='user'@'10.0.0.47' TRIGGER TRG_INS AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @ID=NEW.ID;
INSERT INTO TEST (VAL)
VALUES(@ID);
END
```

It must be something simple that I'm missing

Thanks

Comment: you are trying to get the id with this syntax: SET @ID=NEW.ID; what is new?

Comment: @user1490835 In a trigger, `NEW` is the new row being inserted.

Comment: Works fine here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe5eb/1

Comment: Barmar, when it works fine in your test that tells me it must be a server and/or mysql configuration. Any idea what configuration it might be?  I'm using mysql version 5.6

Comment: What should this be good for? Use Auto_incement for ID in your create table customer statement...

Comment: Hi Ice, the example I provided is just used as an example and is not a real scenario.  In the real scenario I have a form that is being created and populated.  The user that created the form automatically gets authorized to make changes to the form.  These are the [SET] variables I want to use from the trigger to insert into another table each time a record is inserted.  For simplicity I did not want to show the whole sql, rather just demonstrate where I get an error. The [NEW.ID] is actually an auto_increment and I want to insert this id in a different table along with additional parameters.

Comment: Sometimes this just requires you to restart your server while on other occasions, it requires you to recreate the table.